# Clarification on behaviour of QueryTrackingBehavior property of ChangeTracker (EF Core)

Tags: entity-framework-core, change-tracking

Please help with clarification on behaviour of EF Core when `QueryTrackingBehavior` property of `ChangeTracker` is changed.

Let say up to this point in the code, we have everything at default (which means all queries are tracked). Some data has been read/updated and tracked.

Now we update `QueryTrackingBehavior` property of `ChangeTracker` to `NoTracking`. Does this "reset" the tracking of the entities that were read previously?

Let's say we read additional data (not tracked now).

If we change `QueryTrackingBehavior` property of `ChangeTracker` back to `TrackAll`, do the entities read prior of the change retain their tracking so that `SaveChanges()` performs the right updates, ignoring anything that was read while the `ChangeTracker` was set to `NoTracking`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting [QueryTrackingBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.querytrackingbehavior) only affects queries that run subsequently and modifying this property doesn't affect the states of tracked entities.

This can be checked by listing the entities in the change tracker, for example:

```cs
context.Products.Find(1);

context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

context.Products.Find(2);
context.Products.Add(new Product { Id = 21 });

context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll;

context.Products.Find(3);

var ids = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Select(e => ((Product)e.Entity).Id).ToList();
```

The result is:

```
21
1
3
```

As you see, `Product 2` isn't tracked, while entities can still be attached to the change tracker when `QueryTrackingBehavior` is set to `NoTracking`, hence the name "*query* tracking behavior".